# KnockoutJS Data disappears when I add a new item to array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

View the issue on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bFsY/3/

When you click "Add Users" and then click "Add Users" again all of the data in the extensions drop down field disappears. This happened after I added an email column.
The email field gets pre-populated with whatever is selected in the extension dropdown (email is part of its object).

Also, the extensions drop down is unique per line, part of the script tells it to remove it from the array if it exists on a previous line.

**JS**

```
window.usrViewModel = new function () {

    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;

    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.extData = ko.observableArray();
    self.validAccess = [{
        'name': 'No Access',
        'id': 'none'
    }, {
        'name': 'System Settings',
        'id': 'pbx'
    }, {
        'name': 'Accounting',
        'id': 'billing'
    }, {
        'name': 'Full Administrator',
        'id': 'full'
    }];
    self.availableExtData = ko.computed(function () {

        var inUse = [];
        if (!self.selectedItem()) return inUse;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.list(), function (item) {
            if (inUse.indexOf(item.usrExtVal().extension) == -1 && self.selectedItem() != item) inUse.push(item.usrExtVal().extension);
            self.selectedItem().usrEmail(self.selectedItem().usrExtVal().email);
        });

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.extData(), function (item) {
            return inUse.indexOf(item.extension) == -1;
        });

    });

    self.edit = function (item) {
            if (self.selectedItem()) self.save();
            self.selectedItem(item);
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.add = function () {
            if (self.selectedItem()) self.save();

            var newItem = new Users();
            self.selectedItem(newItem);
            self.list.push(newItem);
            self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
    };
    self.remove = function (item) {

        if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {

            self.list.remove(item);
            if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPageIndex()) {
                self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
            }

        }
        $('.error').hide();

    };
    self.save = function () {
            self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.templateToUse = function (item) {
        return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editUsrs' : 'usrItems';
    };

    self.pagedList = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
        return self.list.slice(start, start + size);
    });
    self.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.list().length / self.pageSize()) - 1;
    });
    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
        }
    };
    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPageIndex()) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
        }
    };
    self.allPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var pages = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPageIndex(); i++) {
            pages.push({
                pageNumber: (i + 1)
            });
        }
        return pages;
    });
    self.moveToPage = function (index) {
        self.pageIndex(index);
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(usrViewModel, document.getElementById('usrForm'));

function Users(fname, lname, email, phone, access, usrExtVal, usrEmail) {
    this.fname = ko.observable(fname);
    this.lname = ko.observable(lname);
    this.email = ko.observable(email);
    this.phone = ko.observable(phone);
    this.access = ko.observable(access);
    this.usrExtVal = ko.observable(usrExtVal);
    this.usrEmail = ko.observable(usrEmail);
}
var ajaxResultExt = [{
    'extension': '123',
    'name': 'Stephen',
    'email': 'test@test.com'
}, {
    'extension': '123',
    'name': 'Stephen',
    'email': 'stephen@test.com'
}];

usrViewModel.extData(ajaxResultExt);
```

---

**HTML**

```
                    <fieldset title="Users">
                        <legend>2</legend>
                        <div>
                            <div class="cbp-content">
                                <form id="usrForm">
                                <h2>Users</h2>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-bind='visible: pagedList().length > 0'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>First Name</th>
                                            <th>Last Name</th>
                                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                                            <th>Access</th>
                                            <th>Extension</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;" />
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: pagedList }"></tbody>
                                </table>
                                <!-- ko if: 2 > pagedList().length -->
                                <p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Users</a></p>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <div class="supOneUsr" style="display:none;"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> <span style="color:red;">Please supply at least 1 User with Administrator Rights</span></div>
                                <div class="pagination pull-left" data-bind='visible: pagedList().length > 0'>
                                    <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage">Previous</a></li></ul>
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach: allPages">
                                        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.pageNumber === ($root.pageIndex() + 1) }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.pageNumber, click: function() { $root.moveToPage($data.pageNumber-1); }"></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === maxPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPage">Next</a></li></ul>
                                </div>

                                <br clear="all" />
                                    <script id="usrItems" type="text/html">
                                   <tr>
                                        <td data-bind="text: fname"></td>
                                        <td data-bind="text: lname"></td>
                                        <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
                                        <td data-bind="text: access.asObject && access.asObject() && access.asObject().name"></td>
                                        <td data-bind="text: usrExtVal().extension"></td>
                                        <td data-bind="text: usrEmail"></td>
                                        <td class="buttons">
                                            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                                            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </script>
                                 <script id="editUsrs" type="text/html">
                                   <tr>
                                        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="fname" data-bind="value: fname" /></td>
                                        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="lname" data-bind="value: lname" /></td>
                                        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="phone" data-bind="value: phone" /></td>
                                        <td><select class="accessSelect" data-bind="options: $root.validAccess, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: access, valueAsObject: 'asObject'"></select></td>
                                        <td><select id="extData" data-bind="options: $root.availableExtData, optionsText: 'extension', value: usrExtVal"></select></td>
                                        <td><input id="extEmail" data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="email" data-bind="value: usrEmail" /></td>
                                        <td class="buttons">
                                            <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
                                            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                   </tr>
                                </script>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.

1. `availableExtData` tries to access subproperties of `usrExtVal`, which is sometimes `undefined`. That access causes an error, which prevents further execution of the computed. So you need to first check if `usrExtVal` is set.
2. You have two entries in `ajaxResultExt`, but they both have the same extension. So once you've selected `123` for the first item, there aren't any left for the second, because both `123` values will be removed. So your extensions need to be unique.
3. You're updating `usrEmail` within a loop in `availableExtData`, which doesn't make any sense. It should be in a separate `ko.computed`.

Here is your example with these fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/6bFsY/5/